# Upgrading to gradle 4.0.0 killed the button text color

Tags: android, gradle, button

I was using `gradle 3.5.3` and my buttons look the way i need.

When I upgraded to `gradle 4.0.0` the buttons changed to black, and no matter what I do 
style, theme, `textColor` the color does not change.

Do you know how to fix it?

EDIT:

Correct version of the buttons
[image]

How the buttons look like after upgrading gradle:
[image]

Button layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
android:paddingStart="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:tint="@color/button_keyboard_title_color"
    tools:src="@drawable/ic_delete_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/textButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/KeyboardButton"
    tools:text="0" />


</RelativeLayout>


    <style name="KeyboardButton">
      <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: But which buttons ? Can you provide more detaiils?

Comment: In my case after update app was no build at all. I uninstall all Android Studio, remove all gradle folders in %User%. then remove ".idea" and ".gradle" folders from project path. Install Android Studio 4.0. After that project compiled

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti UI Buttons inside the android app. please check edit

Comment: @LenaBru It shouldn't be related to the gradle plugin update.May be some libraries like the material components library is updated in your build.gradle file. Can you provide the layout and the style?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti when i return the gradle plugin back to 3.5.3 without changing a single line of code, the buttons return to being white.

The layout is a recyclerview with buttons in a grid layout